# DocuSign is displaying MS Word Content Control tags when we send a Word Document with them. Didn't happen before

Tags: docusignapi

[image: DocuSign showing Content Controls]

```
    // fileData is a byte[]
    Document doc = DocuSignServiceImpl.createDocument(retrievedSharepointFile.fileData,
            retrievedSharepointFile.fileName, ".docx")

    ApiClient apiClient = getApiClient()
    EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(apiClient)
    // Create envelopeDefinition object
    EnvelopeDefinition envelope = new EnvelopeDefinition()

    Recipients recipients = new Recipients()
    recipients.setSigners(signers)

    createSignHereTabs(signers)

    String emailSubject = "Please DocuSign: " + doc.name
    emailSubject = emailSubject.length() > 100 ? emailSubject.substring(0, 100) : emailSubject
    envelope.setEmailSubject(emailSubject)     
    envelope.setRecipients(recipients)
    envelope.setDocuments(Collections.singletonList(doc))
    envelope.setStatus("sent")

    EnvelopeSummary results = envelopesApi.createEnvelope(accountId, envelope)
```

We have not changed any code in the past year. It was working all year long and we are sending Word Documents in the exact same format as before. But now we are seeing these content control tags in DocuSign.

Has anything changed in the past month or so that would cause these to start showing up. We send a docx and DocuSign would take the document and only the text within the content control would show up in the signed document, as we want, but now we see the Open and closing of the content control itself.

Comment: Two questions:
1. What API endpoints are you using? maybe you can share your code
2. If you "Save as PDF" to the original .docx, does it also show the Content Control tags in the PDF?

Comment: We call Envelope add the doc Document Java object to the array of docs in Envelope than EnvelopeApit.sendEnvelope(envelope)

Comment: you "Save as PDF" to the original .docx, does it also show the Content Control tags in the PDF?

Comment: Thanks @InbarGazit. It looks like it magically resolved itself. I mean no changes to our code, as it hasn't changed since I wrote it a year ago, and the library jar files are all the same, and same testing environment at DocuSign, but now the Content Controls are not showing anymore as wanted. As to you last question, we don't call a Java api that has "Save as PDF" so all we do is take the byte[] into a DocuSign Document object, file extension .docx and send via the EnvelopeApi. After the users signs, the downloads always ended up being PDFs. I suspect DocuSign converts it automatically.

Comment: I also added our code on how we create and send the Envelope, and in case someone later wants to see some sample code on how to send a document to DocuSign. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

DocuSign converts all documents into PDF (unless you specify you want to use the original HTML with what we call "responsive signing").
So, these markings are a Word (.docx) feature that does not show int he PDF once converted.
It shouldn't matter if the conversion is done by DocuSign when you make an API call and send the document to DocuSign (or via the Java SDK package like you're doing) or if you just use the Word feature to save the document as a PDF. In both case - these markings should not show in the resulting PDF file.

Comment: Totally agree, but someone when previewed/displayed in DocuSign UI it was showing, where it never showed before, and now not showing again. Basically, the one showing them is an anomaly.

Comment: If this happen again, please collect all information, including envelopeID, maybe a full page screenshot etc. so we can try to look into this